# From Honeywell to Google Nest... not cooling?

Tags: electrical, hvac, cooling

I recently changed my thermostat from an old Honeywell 7-day to a Google Nest. I'm an idiot cause I didn't take a photo before replacing it.

now, I feel the air is not cool, just air/fan.

The NEst is connected to a system that has an indoor HVAC and an outdoor ac unit. it works both for heat and cooling. I haven't tested the heat but I feel that if I turn on the AC it produces only fresh air, like a fan would do, not cold at all.

as you see there is an extra yellow wire that I'm not sure what for. the two white wires are labels y1 and w1. there are no labels on the other wires (I'm not sure if there were any tbh)

what do you think is the yellow wire for?

What type of troubleshooting would you recommend before calling an HVAC expert?

can it be the AC is old and i need to replace everything? new liquiq? some fuse?

btw also in my breaker box i see i have 1 switch for the fan and 2 switches for AC condensers they are all ON position

thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace please?

Comment: how do I find it? I think I need a ladder or some, probably hidden somwhere

Comment: it's the big metal box that all your air ducts lead to